# Delayed PC boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, motherboard, post

I have pretty powerful system, that used to be able to go from power on to login screen in under 10 seconds. However, fairly recently i've noticed strange behavior: After press of power on button, most of a hardware starts (fans, HDDs, screens leave low-power state); however, it would take another minute or so until motherboard manufacturer logo would come up. After that it's seems normal, no performance impact after boot, nothing System Logs and Events complain about.

I suspect it might be motherboard, what i'm not sure though if it's a POST check producing delay or UEFI / BIOS, fact that it takes so damn long for logo to even appear makes me suspicious. Right now i'm more curious of ways to analyze what's going on (some type of Verbose POST check would be really handy assuming it's actually happening before motherboard firmware kicks in)

Comment: Most modern motherboards have a small LED display on it showing a status code. That code should show the current job the motherboard is performing and the responses and statuses it gets from the other devices. Does yours have one? You could check to see on which code/status it's stuck for so long

Comment: @Spokey I'm using Gigabyte GA-Z97X, was not able to find anything that would reassemble LED on motherboard. No audio post signals as well.

Comment: Without a debug code it's hard to tell exactly. What you can do is try to remove components (HDDs, GPU, sound cards, RAM!) at a time to see if any of them are causing problems. You can also check your Device Manager to see if anything shows with a warning label (could indicate a driver or hardware issue). How are your temps? Are you overclocking anything? How many W does your PSU have?